# XCode not Opening Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to submit my app to the app store. When I click Product > Archive it goes through the process of archiving the build but doesn't open the organizer screen after. Also when I click Window > Organizer my computer switches desktops but does not open the new window. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Minimize ur screens i think organizer is there ,  behind ur xcode window.Otherwise reopen xcode and do that again.

Comment: Yeah, just buggy behavior. I've seen it too. It opens the Organizer hidden somewhere. It seems to work better in full-screen mode (but not 100%).

Comment: Same here. This process seems very unreliable. Yet another impediment to getting your app updates published on the App Store :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just ForceQuit your Xcode, Simulator and re-open Xcode. Build your project again and open Organizer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, by some reason in edit scheme, under run option and info tab, Executable is selected as none. By changing this to appName.app it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So after none of the suggested solutions here and in other places did not solve my issue, I've finally managed to fix it myself.

For some reason the Scheme wasn't correct. To fix it I clicked the Product -> Scheme -> App name.

After it it worked as expected.